# Why do I get the same object when I use create_list in the FactoryGirl and the sample method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I use factory girl to define a object like this:

```
factory :event do
  #...
  category ['Life', 'Course', 'Speek'].sample
  #...
end
```

Then in the `spec/models/event_spec.rb`, I have this:

```
before(:each) do
  @events = FactoryGirl.create_list(:event, 10, node: school) 
end
  #...
binding.pry
```

But when I used pry to check the `@events`, I found that all the `event` in the `@events` has the same `category`.

I want to know why and how to solve it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code `category ['Life', 'Course', 'Speek'].sample` only runs once (when the factory is defined). If you want to generate a new category each time an `event` is created or built, you can use a `sequence` as follows:

```
sequence(:category) { ['Life', 'Course', 'Speek'].sample }
```

Comment: Don't create a sequence, just put a block around sample: `category { ['Life', 'Course', 'Speek'].sample }`